# How do you calculate your cost projection on amazon S3 for the next few years?

Tags: amazon-s3

Since cost of hosting is always going down at what rate are you estimating it to fall for your cost prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you could do as look at the trend in cost reductions over time. Here is one recent [source](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/what-can-i-say-another-amazon-s3-price-reduction.html):

```
                 Old            New
First 1 TB      $0.150      $0.140 per GB
Next 49 TB      $0.150      $0.125 per GB
Next 50 TB      $0.140      $0.110 per GB
Next 400 TB     $0.130      $0.110 per GB
Next 500 TB     $0.105      $0.095 per GB
Next 4000 TB       $0.080 per GB  $0.080 per GB (no change)
Over 5000 TB    $0.055 per GB   $0.055 per GB (no change)
```

Notice for large data sets there was no change. So you need to look at your current data amount and go off of that.

Personally, I would be conservative and just assume it is not going to cost any less (it could actually start to cost more). If the differences in these projections is actually a significant amount of money your time might be better spent looking at non-cloud hosting solutions for a cost comparison.

Comment: +1 for assuming it's not going to cost less then what you're currently paying.

Answer (score 1):

I use this [Amazon Calculator for Monthly Costs](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html).

It's not infallible, but it's a pretty good guess.

Comment: My question was more about a way to find a conservative prediction on price cut for S3 hosting in the future.

Comment: @plehoux If you word your questions better, you get better answers.  You can't predict the future.   If you can, contact me off-site, and tell me the lottery numbers for next week, and I'll split the jackpot with you.